# For the entire students of the class, get their name, reg.no , stream and arrange their names alphabetically using unions

Tags: c, unions, alphabetical-sort

So I've tried this question using union but there is some error that I am unable to figure out.
In this code, I'm getting an error which says "Warning] passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast." I don't know what does that means. Please someone help me figure this out...
So the code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

union student
{
    char name[25],regno[10],stream[3];
}s[25];

int main()
{
    int i,n,j,temp;
    printf("How many number of students are there?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
          printf("Student Name: ");
          scanf("%s",&s[i].name);
          printf("Reg. No.: ");
          scanf("%s",s[i].regno);
          printf("Stream: ");
          scanf("\n %d",&s[i].stream);
          printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n-1;j++)
        {
            if(strcamp(s[j].name,s[j+1].name)>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,s[j].name);
                strcpy(s[j].name,s[j+1].name);
                strcpy(s[j+1].name,temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",s[i].name,s[i].regno,s[i].stream);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `strcamp()`? And did you intend `union` to be `struct`? Also wrong format spec in `scanf("\n %d",&s[i].stream)`. And remove the leading newline.

Comment: Re the warning you ask about in `strcpy(temp,s[j].name);` the `temp` is `int temp`. But there is another problem too, you are swapping the names but not their other details: you should swap the entire `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are written in comments, here is the final code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    char name[25],regno[10],stream[3];
}s[25];

int main()
{
    int i,n,j;
    char temp[128];
    printf("How many number of students are there?");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
          printf("Student Name: ");
          scanf("%24s",s[i].name);
          printf("Reg. No.: ");
          scanf("%9s",s[i].regno);
          printf("Stream: ");
          scanf("%2s",s[i].stream);
          printf("\n");
    }
    for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n-1;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(s[j].name,s[j+1].name)>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,s[j].name);
                strcpy(s[j].name,s[j+1].name);
                strcpy(s[j+1].name,temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",s[i].name,s[i].regno,s[i].stream);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",s[i].name);` deserves a width limit like `scanf("%24s",s[i].name);`